# QWC2 does not display my map layers on host machine

Tags: qgis-3, qwc2

I have been trying to set up my project following this documentation:
https://github.com/qgis/qwc2-demo-app/blob/master/doc/QWC2_Documentation.md
but I can't get my layers to appear on the map, only when I give it F12 for debug, I see that it only makes requests
GetCapabilities and GetLegendGraphic , but not GetMap

This is my configuration file
themesConfig.json

```
{
    "themes":{
        "items":[
            {
                "title": "Capas Mapa",
                "url":"http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&map=C:/qgis/projects/mtd25shp.qgs",
                "attribution":"Mapa",

                "scales":[
                    1000000,
                    500000,
                    250000,
                    100000,
                    80000,
                    40000,
                    25000,
                    10000,
                    8000,
                    6000,
                    4000,
                    2000,
                    1000,
                    500,
                    250,
                    100
                ],
                "printScales":[
                    80000,
                    40000,
                    25000,
                    10000,
                    8000,
                    6000,
                    4000,
                    2000,
                    1000,
                    500,
                    250,
                    100
                ],
                "printResolutions":[
                    150,
                    300,
                    600
                ],
                "backgroundLayers":[
                    {
                        "name":"mapnik",
                        "visibility":true
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"opentopomap",
                        "visibility":false
                    },
                    {
                      "name":"OpenStreetMap",
                      "visibility":false
                  }
                ],
                "searchProviders":[
                    "coordinates",
                    "uster",
                    {
                        "key": "nominatim",
                        "params": {
                            "countrycodes": "cu"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "mapCrs":"EPSG:4326",
                "additionalMouseCrs":[
                    "EPSG:4326",
                    "EPSG:900913"
                ]
            }
        ],


        "backgroundLayers":[
            {
                "name":"mapnik",
                "title":"Open Street Map",
                "type":"osm",
                "source":"osm",
                "thumbnail":"mapnik.jpg",
                "attribution":"OpenStreetMap contributors",
                "attributionUrl":"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"
            },

            {
              "name": "OpenTopoMap",
              "visible": false,
              "url": "https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            },


        ]
    },
    "defaultScales":[
        4000000,
        2000000,
        1000000,
        400000,
        200000,
        80000,
        40000,
        25000,
        10000,
        8000,
        6000,
        4000,
        2000,
        1000,
        500,
        250,
        100
    ],
    "defaultPrintGrid":[
        {
            "s":10000,
            "x":1000,
            "y":1000
        },
        {
            "s":1000,
            "x":100,
            "y":100
        },
        {
            "s":100,
            "x":10,
            "y":10
        }
    ],
    "defaultWMSVersion":"1.3.0"
}

The project is running on windows 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed problem , the url parameter in Items , instead of being

```
  "url":"http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&map=C:/qgis/projects/mtd25shp.qgs",
```

must be:

```
 "url":"http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?MAP=C:/qgis/projects/mtd25shp.qgs",
```